# PHP SoapServer: How to disable 'Response' appending

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl, soapserver

I am creating a SOAP server (in Symfony using ckWebservicePlugin) which needs to comply with the following structure of request and response (I was given this as an already agreed specification).

**Request:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.net/schemas/USSD">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <USSDMessageRequest>
      <id>43</id>
      <msid>1234567890</msid>
      <data>1*2</data>
    </USSDMessageRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Reponse:**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <USSDMessageResponse>
       <id>43</id>
       <msid>1234567890</msid>
       <data>
          RESPONSE DATA
       </data>
    </USSDMessageResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

The trouble I'm having is with SoapServer always produces the response as name of the requested method + 'Response' appended.

So the **response XML** that is being sent out looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://bw.petr.appsdev/bw/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:USSDMessageRequestResponse>
         <result>
            <id>2</id>
            <msid>1234565789</msid>
            <data>RESPONSE DATA</data>
         </result>
      </ns1:USSDMessageRequestResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**I would like the output to be `<ns1:USSDMessageResponse>` rather than `<ns1:USSDMessageRequestResponse>`**

**The WSDL** I'm using looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="webservices" targetNamespace="http://bw.petr.appsdev/bw/" xmlns:tns="http://bw.petr.appsdev/bw/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <wsdl:types xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://bw.petr.appsdev/bw/">
      <xsd:complexType name="userCredentials">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="msisdn" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="status" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="userCredentialsElement" type="tns:userCredentials"/>
      <xsd:complexType name="USSDResponse">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="msid" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="data" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="USSDResponseElement" type="tns:USSDResponse"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:portType name="webservicesPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="USSDMessageRequest" parameterOrder="userCredentials id msid data">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:USSDMessageRequestRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:USSDMessageResponse" name="USSDMessageResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="webservicesBinding" type="tns:webservicesPortType">
    <soap:binding xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="USSDMessageRequest">
      <soap:operation xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="http://bw.petr.appsdev/bw/USSDMessageRequest" style="rpc"/>
      <wsdl:input xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
        <soap:body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" parts="id msid data" use="literal" namespace="http://bw.petr.appsdev/bw/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        <soap:header xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" message="tns:USSDMessageRequestRequest" part="userCredentials" use="literal" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
        <soap:body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" parts="result" use="literal" namespace="http://bw.petr.appsdev/bw/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        <soap:header xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" message="tns:USSDMessageResponse" part="userCredentials" use="literal" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:message name="USSDMessageRequestRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="userCredentials" element="tns:userCredentialsElement"/>
    <wsdl:part name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="msid" type="xsd:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="data" type="xsd:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="USSDMessageResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="userCredentials" element="tns:userCredentialsElement"/>
    <wsdl:part name="result" type="tns:USSDResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:service xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="webservicesService">
    <wsdl:port xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="webservicesPort" binding="tns:webservicesBinding">
      <soap:address xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" location="http://bw.petr.appsdev/bw/webservices.php"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Have checked SoapServer documentation, browsed through Pro Xml And Web Services by R. Richards and just can't figure out how to tell SoapServer what the response name should be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this dirty SoapVar hack:

```
public function USSDMessageRequest() {
        $result = '<ns1:USSDMessageResponse> ... </ns1:USSDMessageResponse>'; // ns1 is dirty, depends on the SoapServer implementation
        $result = new SoapVar($result, XSD_ANYXML);
        return $result;
    }
```

It has worked for me in a similar problem (I have not tested it with your web service, though).

Answer (score 1):

Do you create SoapServer in WSDL mode? I mean you have construct SoapServer like this:

```
new SoapServer('path/to/wsdl', $options);
```

the first parameter must not be null. Then the SoapServer should create response according to the WSDL. If you have troubles anyway, try it with the newest release of PHP.

Comment: Thanks. We create the server in WSDL mode. Tried all kinds of different ways to approach it.

Comment: @xmedeko I have a similar problem. I would like to customise the 'ns1' node in the SOAP response. My question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20836908/386579