# zend soap server response set custom ns1 namespace

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, soapui, zend-soap

I am using Zend_Soap_Server (WSDL mode) for outputting an xml response to the client calls.
However, i want to set a custom name for the **ns1** namespace in the response.

I noticed that the namespace in the response is set by default like: '**ns1:getDoubleResponse**' where '**getDouble**' is the server method being called.

Here is my controller and SOAP server setup:

```
class TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function testAction() {

        // diable laoyouts and renderers
        $this->getHelper ( 'viewRenderer' )->setNoRender ( true );
        $server = new Zend_Soap_Server ('http://example.com/public/test/testwsdl'); 
        $server->setClass ( 'Application_Model_test');

        // register exceptions that generate SOAP faults
        $server->registerFaultException('Application_Model_soapException');

        // handle request
        $server->handle ();
    }

    public function testwsdlAction() {
        // diable laoyouts and renderers
        $this->getHelper ( 'viewRenderer' )->setNoRender ( true );      
        $wsdl = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover ();

        $wsdl->setClass ( 'Application_Model_test');    
        $wsdl->setUri ('http://example.com/public/test/test');

        // handle request
        $wsdl->handle ();
    }
}
```

This is my model code:

```
class Application_Model_test
{
    /**
     * Returns the double of an integer value
     * @param integer $int
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDouble($int)
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument ( '1.0', 'utf-8' );

        $response = $doc->createElement("IntegerResult");
        $val = $doc->createElement("Value");
        $val->appendChild ($doc->createTextNode($int * 2));     
        $response->appendChild($val);           

        $doc->appendChild ($response);      
        $result = $doc->saveXML();
        return $result;
    }   
}
```

This is the request i see, as per SOAP UI:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:test="http://example.com/public/test/test">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <test:getDouble soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <int xsi:type="xsd:int" xs:type="type:int" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance">3</int>
      </test:getDouble>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is the associated response, as per SOAP UI:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/public/test/test" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:getDoubleResponse>
         <return xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
&lt;IntegerResult>&lt;Value>6&lt;/Value>&lt;/IntegerResult></return>
      </ns1:getDoubleResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I just want to change the `<ns1:getDoubleResponse>` in SOAP response to something like `<ns1:TestResult>`

How can i fix namespace? I don't mind throwing the response through DOM or Xpath.
I am also interested in extending the Zend_Soap_Server for customizing the response.

**UPDATE:**

I have extended the Zend_Soap_Server with a class, and now tried to send a custom response through the handle() method.

```
// TestController.php
//$server = new Zend_Soap_Server ('http://example.com/public/test/testwsdl');
$server = new TestSoapServer ('http://example.com/public/test/testwsdl');
```

And this is the class that extends Zend_Soap_Server, and handles the response:

```
// TestController.php
class TestSoapServer extends Zend_Soap_Server 
{
    public function __construct($wsdl, $options = null)
    {
        return parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
    }

    public function handle($request = null)
    {
      $result = parent::handle($request);
      $result = str_replace("getDoubleResponse", "TestResult", $result);
      return $result;       
    }
}
```

But now, when i run the request in SOAP UI, i see an empty response. Don't know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, i decided to parse the incoming SOAP request manually in my Controller:

```
// TestController.php
class TestSoapServer extends Zend_Soap_Server 
{
    // Handle the request and generate suitable response    
    public function handle($request = null)
    {
      if (null === $request) {    
       $request = file_get_contents('php://input');
      }
      // Parse request, generate a static/dynamic response and return it.

      // return parent::handle($request); // Actual response

    // Custom response
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($request);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $xml = $doc->saveXML($doc->documentElement);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $int = $xml->body->envelope->body->getdouble->int;
    $value = $int * 2;

    $result = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
               SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"             
               xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
               xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/public/test/test" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
               <SOAP-ENV:Body>
               <ns1:TestResult>';

     $result .= '<IntegerResult><Value>'.$value.'</Value></IntegerResult>';

    $result .= '</ns1:TestResult>
                </SOAP-ENV:Body>
                </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

    return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this solution, but some of my response is cut off, for example `</SOAP-ENV:Envelo` instead of `</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`. Is there a set length to a SOAP response?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirements in my jax ws implementation. And surprisingly i found out,

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839441/change-message-name)

Similarly i don't think zend framework gives you control over message name. Read zend  specification for confirmation.

Only option you have is to parse response as per your requirement after receiving at client side using DOM or Xpath. I am not familiar with zend framework so can't give u working code right now.

Comment: Well, the client does not like to parse the response. So i had to send response as per his requirement.